# document.getElementById("").focus() not focusing on desired item.Some timeout value using setTimeout works sometimes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, focus

Using `setTimeOut(()=>{e.focus()}, 100)` works sometimes and sometimes not. Is there any deterministic alternative to this, which makes sure that element gets focused anyhow. Also I don't want to use positive timeout value inside `setTimeout` function.

Comment: Can you please show us a snippet of what you have so far (other than the `e.focus()` line).

Comment: @mayank goyal - Could you please reproduce the issue?

Comment: Try adding your `focus()` inside `if (document.getElementById('')) { }`. This will run only when the element is loaded in the DOM.

Comment: @AndrewL64 the use case is: I am opening a dialog on click of a button. I have to set focus on menu-items inside dialog on button click. .focus() is not working in this scenario.

Comment: @mayankgoyal - Add the code in the question.

Comment: Have you looked at `componentDidMount`, I am a bit out of touch with React but I seem to remember that being the handler for when something has rendered? I could be wrong as I cannot remember the lifecycle management.

Comment: If you are using react, using ref is the best way to reach elements in dom. Check out useRef in react docs.

Comment: @GrahamRitchie How do i access componentdidMount of Dialog, which is from a library and it's props doesn't have any such lifecycle method

Comment: sorry bud, it was ages since I moved away from react so I did say I could be wrong. @kubilaysalih mentioned `useRef` so that may be the correct way of doing it. You are looking for some hook that triggers after dialog open, I am sure there will be one.

Answer (score 0):

userRef approach works in this scenario since element gets focus once it is rendered so it's a deterministic approach to focus on an element.